# Managing Azure storage account with IP whitelisting using build agents with random IP's

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I want to manage an Azure Storage Account which IP whitelisting enabled, in a pipeline which runs on an Azure DevOps build agent hosted by MS which have random IP's.

As expected, as soon as I try to run any commands which need access to the storage account's resources (e.g. `az storage container list --account-name {account-name}`) this fails with a 403 error message.

The typical solution for this is to temporary add the IP of the agent to the whitelist table:

```
# Get agent IP
$agentIP = (New-Object net.webclient).downloadstring("https://api.ipify.org")

# Add agent IP to whitelist
az storage account network-rule add --resource-group "$ResourceGroup" --account-name "$AccountName" --ip-address "$agentIp" | Out-Null

# Allow whitelist change to propagate
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

# Perform tasks on storage account
az storage container list --account-name "$AccountName"

# Remove agent IP from whitelist
az storage account network-rule remove --resource-group "$ResourceGroup" --account-name "$AccountName" --ip-address "$agentIp" | Out-Null
```

But this is where things get kind of strange, when I run this script multiple times (tried 20 cycles by now) on my local PC, it never encounters any errors.
However, when I run the same script on a DevOps build agent, it will error out most of the time.
I tried increasing the sleep time to 60, even 120 seconds (which significantly slows the pipeline...), but it still errors out most of the time. Every now and then it will succeed.
I even tried adding 'debug' lines, re-acquiring the agent IP and echo'ing it, just to make sure the agent is not switching IP's mid-pipeline or something, but it remains the same.

So what gives? Why is the storage account's firewall behaving so weird against a DevOps agent vs my local PC?

BTW: If I completely turn off the firewall by running `az storage account update --name "$AccountName" --default-action Allow" (and enable it again afterwards), it works all the time, but this is not allowed by security policies.